# How can I make an array where each element is associated with 2 other values?

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

I have an input which is something like this

```
1 3 2
0 4 1
0 10 5 
1 7 3
0 22 9
```

I need to store the middle elements into an array, and then sort that array, but each element has to still be associated with the 2 elements from input, for example, 3 has to be associated with 1 and 2. I am thinking to make a 1D array where each element is represented by 3 numbers, if that's possible, then sort it by the middle number. Is that possible? If not what is a good way of doing that? Also, I am working in C.

Comment: Make a struct for the 3 numbers. You can make an array of those structs and sort it with `qsort` or whatever other method you prefer.

Comment: Use an array of structures and sort by the middle field.

Answer (score 1):

Use a struct.

```
struct MyStruct{
    int a,b,c;
}MyArray[5];
```

Now sort for MyArray[i].b;